# MySQL - SELECT TOCHAR "Date"

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm asking myself if is possible to convert date `TOCHAR` using MySQL.

I want to run *simple* `SELECT` query to output date with `TOCHAR`.

```
Date: 02.05.2017  -> TOCHAR
```

Comment: TO_CHAR converts a datetime to a string for sql server. DATE_FORMAT does the same in MySQL read... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: I will show this to my mentor. He probably don't know what is the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Try the function `DATE_FORMAT(date,format)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use date_format to formating date type in mysql - DATE_FORMAT(date,format)

for example

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2017-05-01 22:23:00', ''%d %b %Y');
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp